# How to return innertext of sibling element

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

In GTM i'm trying to return the inner text of a sibling element of the clicked element.

```html
<div class="repair-item-n ">
  <div class="repair-slide--54894d33-6c88-488f-95d7-3ec9b6a3ade4">
    <div class="restoration_wrap text-center">
      <img class="restoration-image">
    </div>
    <p class="title">Bags</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

For example, on click of class "restoration-image" I want to return the value "Bags".

I have multiple occurrences of this HTML on the page with varinats such as "Shoes", "Hats" etc so I want to know on click of each, which would be the respective text of the "title" class

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var images = document.querySelectorAll('.restoration-image');

images.forEach(function (image) {
    image.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
        var parent = this.parentNode;
        var nextSibling = parent.nextElementSibling;

        alert(nextSibling.innerText)
    })
});
```

Comment: Hi Richard,
Thanks for the help! For GTM there's a requirement of a CustomJavascriptVariable to "The javaScript must define a function with a return value."
When adding "return(nextSibling.innerText)" I receive "undefined" in GTM

Answer (score 0):

This should work for GTM custom JavaScript variables.

```
function getImgTitle() {
  if({{event}} === 'gtm.click') {
    var image = {{Click Element}};
    var parent = image.parentNode,
        nextSibling = parent.nextElementSibling;
    return nextSibling.innerText;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this in a Custom Javascript Variable:

#### `Click - Repair Item Title`

```js
function() {
  var clickedEl = {{Click Element}};
  if (!clickedEl) return;

  // Find the mutual parent element
  var repairItemEl = clickedEl.closest(".repair-item-n");
  if (!repairItemEl) return;

  var titleEl = repairItemEl.querySelector(".title");
  if (!titleEl) return;

  return titleEl.innerText
}}
```